# Django error page doesn't show with syntax error

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a custom Django 500 page and debug set to False. When my app encounters a runtime error, I get the Django stack trace as expected.

However when I have a syntax error, I get the cryptic Apache "Internal Server Error" page, and have to debug Django by tailing the apache log.

*Why doesn't Django show the error page?*

I believe I used to get Django error pages for all errors - not just runtime ones.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have the stacktrace mailed to you which is enabled by default. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors. Also its good that django does not show any debug information when DEBUG=False, it would expose information on your server and configuration.

Comment: @Jingo I don't think that would help, because of reasons explained in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the interpreter running django (started by apache) won't even start, so there is no way to render the actual page.

What goes into apache log is the python interpreter's `stderr`

From [mod_wsgi documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques)

> When using mod_wsgi, unless you or the web framework you are using
>   takes specific action to catch exceptions and present the details in
>   an alternate manner, the only place that details of uncaught
>   exceptions will be recorded is in the Apache error log files. The
>   Apache error log files are therefore your prime source of information
>   when things go wrong.

To summarize: The `SyntaxError` means that the *code is not python* so there is no one to catch the exception and show it in a friendly web page.

I don't know to how to change this in Apache, but at least in my tests running [green unicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) + [nginx](http://nginx.org/) I do get stacktraces on the 500 page if I run my green unicorn workers with `--debug` - even when Django fails to load because of the `SyntaxError`

Comment: So there's no way around this? Would it work under Django's server? Or perhaps nginx?

Comment: Using Django's server would refuse to start the server